# button with image with transparent background

Tags: android, image, button, flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a 'custom button' for my app.
I have an image of egg with transparent backgroung and I need this image to be a button that ignore tapping on the transparent part.

Right now , I use gesturedetcetor , I also tried inkwell ,they are both detect tapping all the whole image, include the transparent back.

```
Align(
    alignment: Alignment(0, 0.75),
    child: Container(
        width: swidth * 0.75,
        height: sheight * 0.6,
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                    pushes--;
                });
            },
        child: Image.asset(
        'images/egg.png',
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
    )),
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome **maor ts** in Stackoverflow and Flutter dev.

I was very interesting with your question and your problem, so I decided to solve it with a new package you can use.

This package is [transparent_image_button](https://pub.dev/packages/transparent_image_button) which I recently coded it.

You can use it as this example

`TransparentImageButton.assets( "assets/images/egg.png", 
    width: 200, 
    onTapInside: () => print("You tapped the image."), 
    onTapOutside: () => print("You tapped outside the image."), 
)`

As you can see, you can set function when you tapped on image and another function when you tapped outside the image.

I hope other people can benefit from it also. Thanks for giving me the idea with your question.

Comment: I am happy to know that it works for you. Please make it as answer.

Comment: i tried but maybe because im a new account its dosnt count my vote

Comment: You can't upvote my answer. But you can make it as the answer of the question, please click grey true symbol ✅ front of my answer and it will be green ✔️ after that.

Comment: not in case if anyone need to use CachedNetworkImage

Answer (score 0):

In the way, you are implementing it will detect the tap on all over the image.

I will suggest you add the transparent view on the image in the fill area and then add `GestureDetector` on that view. In this way, you can avoid the click on the transparent area.

Comment: i dont realy understand , can you explain what is the meaning of transparent view?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code may solved your issue

```
Row(children: <Widget>[
      GestureDetector(child: Container(
        width: swidth * 0.75,
        height: sheight * 0.6,
      ),onTap: (){
        setState(() {
          pushes--;
        });
      },),
      Image.asset(
        'images/egg.png',
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
      )
    ],)
```